# Increment img name in lines of html code?

Tags: html, editor, dreamweaver, increment

I need to generate 398 lines of html code. This is the first line:

```
{<img src="images/blackcelebratory/2014/001.jpg"/>}
```

then I need to increment the image name up to 398.jpg. So the name of the image on the last line would be:

.../398.jpg

Is there a way, using a text editor, or Dreamweaver, or a bit of code, to automate generating these lines of code?

Comment: Is there a reason why you would want 398 images on one web page? Why dont you do some javascript that will allow the user to click through them as desired. It would definitely improve the page load of the site.

Comment: Actually, there is some javascript which will call the lines of code into an image gallery, where users can look at the images one at a time. Is there a way to run a loop in a text editor?

Comment: @juniorspecial do you just want the static html of the 398 images (i.e. you don't want to generate them dynamically on page load)? if so, just open this link and copy them out of the HTML section: [static IMG's from 1-398](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/c2Bxk/2/)

Comment: Yes, I just want the static html.

Comment: Great! I copied and pasted that and it worked great! How did you put those together?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
for ($x=0; $x<=398; $x++) {
echo "<img src="images/blackcelebratory/2014/". $x .".jpg"/>";
} 
?>
```

Comment: When I put that code into the html page, I get the message "Load failed: No Data Found."

Comment: you must put the php file and run in apache or can using the jquery

Answer (score 0):

In jquery:

```
for(var i = 1; i<399; i++){
    $("body").append("<img src='images/blackcelebratory/2014/"+i+".jpg' />");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a loop: [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/c2Bxk/)

```
<script>
  for(i = 1; i < 399; i++) {
    var img = document.createElement('IMG');
    var j = i.toString();
    var num = [0, 0].slice(0, j.length < 4 ? 3 - j.length : 0).join('') + j;
    img.src = "images/blackcelebratory/2014/" + num + ".jpg";
    document.body.appendChild(img);
  }
</script>
```